# mongodb + mongoose: query not entering .find function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting start with mongodb and mongoose but am having problems querying a database. There are a number of tutorials online for what I am trying to do but it just doesn't seem to work for me. **My problem is that the .find() function is not even being called and the collection is not being displayed.** I have a collection called Subjects in which I know there are some values (I manually entered them in the mongodb command line). I only tried including pertinent code but let me know if anything else is needed. Thanks in advance.

**app.js file**

```
require('./models/model.js');
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/test');
var Subject = mongoose.model('Subjects');

Subject.find( { }, function (err, subjects) {
    if(err) console.log("Error");   // There is no "Error"
    console.log("Made it");         // There is no "Made it"
    console.log(subjects);
});
```

**model.js file**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var SubjectsSchema = new Schema ({
    subject: { type: String }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Subjects', SubjectsSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [`mongoose.connect`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-connect) instead of `mongoose.createConnnection` to open the default connection pool that will be used by models created using `mongoose.model`:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
```

Comment: Thank you. On a related note, I didn't see any subjects. On the mongo command line I type in db.Subjects.find() and I see what I entered. However, when I insert new data 

`var sub = new Subject( { subject: 'some subject' } );
sub.save(function(err){ if(err) console.log(err);});`

I see the output. What is going on here?

Comment: Try `mongoose.model('Subjects', SubjectsSchema, 'Subjects');` instead. Mongoose "helpfully" lower-cases and pluralizes model names to get the collection name if you don't provide an explicit name in the `model` call.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. I checked my mongo db and apparently had a 'subjects' collection as well as a 'Subjects' collection.